Sealing an unfinished-basement ceiling without putting in ... a ceiling?
100-year old stone house, eastern Pennsylvania, USA. Wondering if folks have creative ideas for our basement, which we’d like to upgrade from mostly unfinished to partly finished.
The space is currently pretty raw - clean cement floor, old plaster and paint on the walls (made of pennsylvania schist), good windows, otherwise unfinished. The ceiling is large exposed beams running just under the floorboards of the first floor - there’s no subfloor at all - and all the ductwork for our central air, plumbing from our boiler, and electrical from our circuit box runs pretty tidily along or just below those beams.
To make a clean and usable rec-room space, we have to - at minimum - seal the walls and ceiling enough to stop the constant rain of dust and grit that currently coats everything we store down there.
I’d like to lime-plaster the walls. The ceilings are the question mark. I don’t want to cover any of those ducts, wires, etc., and make them harder to work on when needed. I also want to lose any of the height we have now, which makes the basement feel spacious. 
Is there a fabric or mesh that’d work well affixed directly to the underside of the flooring above? Or is there some other creative way to seal out the dust and cut down on heat/cooling loss without covering all those convenient house-guts and losing the high ceilings?

Good compressed-air blast then spray paint?

Are the floor boards tight together or is there some gaps between them?  Paint alone might not seal the gaps if any.

First choose the "partly finished" area and only work on that.   You don't have to do the whole basement at once.  Then ..
For the ceiling

Remove anything that is no longer in use.  In my house (1894) that meant more than half the crap up there.   Gas lighting pipes from the 20s.  Random disused knobs and tubes left over from electrical upgrades.  Miles and miles, and miles, and ... miles ... of disused low voltage wiring ... telephone, fax, cable coax, alarm system.  OMG.. Miles of it.  Couldn't they foresee wifi?  :)  Disused gas and water lines to appliances and rooms of generations past.  Get rid of anything not in use.  [Note re "disused" water lines: If you have some live water lines snaking around but going nowhere, invest 10 cents in an end cap so you can cut them off and remove them!]

From what's left, wrap plastic and tape around any valves, junction boxes, etc ... anything that needs maintenance or gets "used" from time to time.

If there are particularly busy or messy areas remaining, you can cover them tightly in black fabric or partly block them with thin plywood.  YOu don't have to box anything in completely. Just enough to make any ghastly messes less visible, which will open up the room a bit.  Don't do the whole ceiling this way ... that will make the room close in.

Vacuum, then wet mop, then vacuum again what's left to remove as much dust as possible

Spray paint everything black.

Get creative with LED lighting.


For the walls
I decided to just live with it, and enjoy the ambiance of the big old stones.  They were nicely repointed before I bought the house.  Plastering them is I believe impossible.  You'd have to build a stud wall inside of them with a vapor barrier behind it.  You'd lose a lot of space that way.  If parts of the wall are shedding a lot of gunk, you can hang a tapestry over (but not touching) those areas to keep it behind.

Great narrative. Andrew, at step 5, as an alternative to spray paint, consider applying a thick spray-on coating similar to truck bed liner or Rhino Shield. This would bridge the gaps between the floorboards and stop the rain of dust and grit forever, as well as providing an air and vapor barrier between basement and the floor above.

I assumed the dust and grit is coming mainly from the walls.  There should not be a constant supply of it from the ceiling!  Certainly not after cleaning it well.  If there is, you have to figure out why.   I don't think sealing the ceiling is necessary and a thick coating of anything will make it very very hard to find and repair cables and pipes when needed.    Natural stone walls will definitely shed grit and I do not think you can stop it.  Anything you apply to it will become part of the problem or make it worse.

There can be if it's old wood flooring that lets dust between the cracks. In that case I would consider spraying with Plasti-Dip. You can buy it in quantity from 'dip your car' sites in any color that you want.

IDK about black.  I get you want black to make the "junk" up there less visible, but to me that would make the area seem darker, which a basement already is.

@Huesmann this is veering into decorating territory, possibly over a cliff and into an abyss of it. :)  But up there it's all sewer pipes, BX, NM, irregular hand-cut diagonal bracing, steam pipes (in use or not, nobody wants to remove those!), etc etc ... if you paint it white it looks like a Costco.   You're right about black but at least it disappears.  You decorate around that.  I suppose with white you could embrace a theme like NYC warehouse cheaply converted to restaurant with nothing but spray paint and junkyard furniture. :)

I would consider stapling up some white sheets instead.  Cover the Costco, make it look like clouds. :)
